# how do i suppress seds unnessary output while using option -e?

Tags: shell-script, sed

why n option is not working here

```
   [root@testgfs2 final]# echo a b c | sed -ne 's/[[:blank:]]/"/gp' -ne 's/^/"/pg' -ne 's/$/"/pg'
    a"b"c
    "a"b"c
    "a"b"c"
```

i just need :

```
"a"b"c"
```

actually i want sed to do somehting like :

```
echo a b c d | sed ...
```

output:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using `p` as a modifier which prints the "pattern space", i.e. result. To fix your example just do:

```
echo a b c | sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]/"/g' -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g
```

You may also consider using something like:

```
echo a b c | sed -e 's/\(\w*\)/"\1"/g'
```

instead.

Comment: +1. Or the shorter ERE version: `sed -r "s/\w+/'&'/g"`.

Comment: what does `\w*` stands for or does

Comment: @munish: `\w` is a GNU sed extension and is equivalent to this group `[[:alnum:]_]`. What version of sed are you using?

Comment: Which means `sed "s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/'&'/g"` would be standard, more correct (as you want non-blanks, not just alnums) and more portable.